How to run 'show run' and enter 'conf t' without password via remote SSH
I have a Cisco Catalyst 4500 L3 Switch and have a user called user1. Switch IP is 192.168.1.1.
I have a server which IP is 192.168.2.1.
I created a user in my switch and I can SSH into my switch without password:
root@192.168.2.1:~# ssh 192.168.1.1 'show version'

MPC8548 CPU at 1GHz, Cisco Catalyst 4948E-F
Last reset from Reload
2 Virtual Ethernet interfaces
48 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
4 Ten Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
511K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.

Configuration register is 0x2102
Connection to 192.168.1.1 closed by remote host.

But this fails:
root@192.168.2.1:~# ssh 192.168.1.1 'show run'

Line has invalid autocommand "show run"Connection to 192.168.1.1 closed by remote host.

I'm going to do something so that user1 can do en, conf t and doing the changes like changing switch port description.
How can I do that?


Line has invalid autocommand "show run"

This is because the user does not have permission to run that command. This is easily remedied by setting the privilege level for the user:
username user1 privilege 15 ...

(or whatever priv your "show run" is limited to.)
